# Google Drive: huge difference between file size and storage used

Tags: google-drive

As you can see in the image below, a file that is 68MB is somehow using up 1GB of storage in my google drive. I have a few other files with this issue.

I have uploaded multiple versions of this file over the last few months, so perhaps old versions are being saved somehow? If so, can anyone advise as to how to delete all but the most current.

If it's relevant, the file type ".shp" is a shapefile for use with ArcGIS.

Any tips on the issue and how to fix it will be great.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Click the file name in the Google Drive panel and the File Details sidebar will open. Go to the "Modified" section and click the Clock icon. You'll now have access to previous versions and here you can also delete any old versions.